Why is a relative pronoun needed in the following sentence?
Just ignore the chemistry information as the sentence came from a textbook about chemistry.

The difference is exemplified by the two similar reactions: whereas the [chemical] base attacks at the hydrogen of the carbon hydrogen chemical bond, it is the silicon of the silicon hydrogen chemical bond that is attacked.

For that sentence, can it be rewritten as, "whereas the base attacks at the hydrogen of the carbon hydrogen chemical bond, the base attacks the silicon of the silicon hydrogen chemical bond"? This question exemplifies my following - second - intended question.
My question why is the part "it is the silicon of (a term} " used? Is it preferred or required; if so, why?

The 'silicon of' is used because the element silicon is one of the two elements in the 'silicon hydrogen' chemical bond. The alternative would be 'the hydrogen' (of the bond). What exactly don;t you understand?

I take it that the first reaction attacks the hydrogen part of the carbon/hydrogen pair. So when we look at a silicon/hydrogen pair, we might expect the same focus in the chemical reaction. But in fact it is the silicon part that is attacked. In other words, the grammar here is about a change in word order to emphasise the point being made.

Please take a look at the edits. Your questions were not properly asked. All those make your questions confusing. Your rewrite is better because it has the same structure as the other clause.

@Lambie thank you for the edit. Today is the boxing day so my brain is on leisure mode.

@MichaelHarvey Thank you for comment. I think PeterKirkpatrick 's comment is what I was asking about that sentence.

@PeterKirkpatrick In sum, the change in word order emphasize the point being made. Alright I learnt something today. Thank you.


It is the silicon of the silicon hydrogen chemical bond that is attacked.

This is an it-cleft sentence.  This word order enables us to emphasise certain parts of the sentence.  The focus is brought to the front.
The OP’s

the base attacks the silicon of the silicon hydrogen chemical bond

doesn't have such emphasis.
We don't necessarily need to use the it-cleft; another tool is the wh-cleft.  An example is
What is attacked is the silicon (atom).
Here the focus is brought to
the back.
Wikipedia cleft sentences

Further to the good answer from Seowjooheng Singapore about focus of presentation.
Under what circumstances do we need to make a piece of information salient?
Consider:  You have two compounds, both involving hydrogen, and these  compounds are subjected to a base. With the carbon-hydrogen compound the base attacks the hydrogen. But that is not what happens with the silicon-hydrogen compound, where the base attacks at the silicon.
So, if you have a situation where a certain expectation on the part of the reader would not be unreasonable but is not correct (i.e. the base  will always attack hydrogen), you can use the it-cleft to highlight the piece of information that shows what is actually happening, contrary to that expectation.

The police required me to bring my two dogs to you, doctor. As you can see, one is a pit bull and the other is a papillon. It is the papillon that needs to be put down for biting two people. The pit bull needs to be tested for rabies.

